# Mercurial: Cannot edit config file because of parse error

Tags: mercurial

I was adding rebase as an extension to mercurial. So, within the config file, I accidentally left a space in front of a line.

Now, the file doesn't work (as expected), so I tried to fix it by calling

```
$ hg config --edit
```

which is how I had previously edited it. However, the terminal now returned

```
hg: parse error at /Users/mathwizurd/.hgrc:25:  rebase =
unexpected leading whitespace
```

I couldn't run any mercurial command to fix the config file.

How do you fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I couldn't use any Mercurial command, I just edited the file itself with nano, and it worked.

```
$ nano /Users/mathwizurd/.hgrc
```

I edited the file and removed the extra space.

Answer (score 0):

The "Unexpected leading whitespace" error message often happens when a .hgrc file has a line that starts with whitespace. if you want to solve this, you have to remove the whitespace and save the file.